How can a 240V device with a single hot terminal be wired with two 120v hot wires?
US based.
I am looking to install this radiant floor themostat: https://www.homedepot.com/p/QuietWarmth-120-Volt-240-Volt-7-Day-Programmable-Floor-Warming-Thermostat-THERMPRO/318528774
The thermostat claims to be capable of both 120V and 240V wiring. However it only has two Line terminals, one for hot, one for neutral. Given that pulling off a 240V circuit from the panel will result in two 120v hot wires, as well as neutral and ground, how would this wiring work?
Is the thermostat expecting a single 240V hot wire? My understanding of split phase 240V is that they cannot simply be recombined.
Thanks.
Edit: Included a picture of the back of the thermostat where the terminals are.


Good chance it does not need neutral to work at 240v, so you could use two hots(no neutral) or a hot and neutral.  It should come with wiring instructions for both.

240V circuits do not necessarily need neutral.  The white wire in /2+gnd cable can be marked with black or color tape to make it the 2nd hot with no neutral.

If you have 240volt heaters and a 240volt thermostat you don’t need a neutral. Just the two hot wires from the main panel. Harper and Crip659 are correct.

Did you configure and buy a 240V heating cable?  If the cable is designed for 240V, you use a 240V supply without a neutral and this thermostat can switch that.   If the supply cable also has a neutral you don't use it but that would be unusual, because a heated floor normally has its own new /2 cable run to the breaker panel.  You wouldn't buy a /3 cable for this.

I reviewed the installation instructions. Those terminals are hot/neutral on 120V and L1/L2 on 208V or 240V. You don't switch the ground through the thermostat, it gets directly connected. Your heating coils almost certainly don't need neutral, but if for some reason they do you can hook it up directly and just switch L1/L2.

So if I understand you correctly, hot 1 and hot 2 can go onto L1 and L2 respectively, with no need for neutral and ground?

@AndyHall, that is correct. This thermostat does not need neutral and ground. If the heating elements have a connection for ground, you should connect ground there. Neutral can be capped off.

The heating cable should have a ground sheath that needs to be connected to the ground wire from your power source.   That connection can be made in the junction box behind the thermostat, along with the box itself if it's metal.  The thermostat body may not require a ground connection or facilitate the ones you have to make but you need to make them.

The comments got it. :)

The US system is actually very flexible. In most buildings you can wire up any combination of:

120V only - hot + neutral - used for most "regular" receptacles for plug-in devices, lighting, disposal, dishwasher, washing machine, gas clothes dryer, some HVAC equipment, etc.
240V only - hot + hot, no neutral - used for electric water heater, some HVAC equipment (including most electric resistant heat), most cooktops, EV charging, etc.
120V/240V combination - hot + hot + neutral - used for electric clothes dryer, most electric ovens and ranges (oven/cooktop combination) and a few other large appliances

So yes, the two "120V hot" wires can be combined to make a 240V circuit. That is 100% normal in the US. Most devices are designed to work one way or the other, but there is no fundamental reason you can't have a thermostat (or any other device) that will work on both 120V (hot + neutral) and 240V (hot + hot). A thermostat needs to get some power for itself (control panel, timer, sensors, etc.) from somewhere, but just like a typical computer power supply will be rated for 100V - 250V (so that it can be used worldwide with different cables but the same electronics), a thermostat can be designed so that it can work with 120V or 240V power.

Combined should be changed to used.  Combined has the notion connecting together.  Can you/me plug in a computer power supply on a 240v(6-15) US circuit, without neutral?

@crip659 sure, a 240V computer power supply only has L1/L2/G connections, it will work fine on a 6-15 with an appropriate cord. It will also be more efficient in most cases than on a 120V circuit. I have PCs in my basement running on a 240V UPS hooked up to a 6-20 twistlock, no issues. It works great for stuff that runs 24x7 where efficiency matters.

@KMJ I understand how higher voltage is more efficient at power delivery in various scenarios, but not how a single computer PSU is internally more efficient if it is auto sensing (like most laptop bricks) or manually switched (like many towers) to a 240V supply.  Not to start a conversation here about that, can you just give any pointers?

@jay613 It all depends on power supply efficiency. My hunch is that on a laptop brick that far more is wasted (since it is easy to do so as the power supply sits in open air) as heat and the total load so low that difference between 120V and 240V is extremely small. Next up is a typical auto-switching (100V - 250V) desktop at a few hundred watts - might be a small efficiency improvement at 240V vs. 120V. But at a much higher level - e.g., a server rack with an advanced power supply feeding multiple devices - then the improvements start to creep in, but even then, a 10% improvement (which

would be significant) on a single circuit would only save a few $ a month. When you take the same type of thing and scale it up to dozens (big company) or thousands (data center) then the savings get to be significant. But there are other extremes: On a pure resistance load, the only thing higher voltage gets you is smaller wires (which is a lower installation cost but not running cost). And on a large motor load, higher voltage really does result in better performance, though I don't know how much (if any) difference it makes on efficiency.

Yes sure in big data centers, and similarly I know the lights in the office buildings I've worked at are 480V.  You can run an entire floor on a pair of #14 wires.  We had one guy specially trained to swap bulbs and ballasts on hot 480V fixtures.  Maybe KMJ's UPS is more efficient on 240 if it's full-time feeding a bunch of PCs.   IDK.   But as you say, in a single consumer computer PSU the difference is likely negligible or zero, and in a floor heating cable, you have to use the design voltage and you get pretty much 100% efficiency either way.

@jay613 check out the Wikipedia page on the '80 PLUS' power supply efficiency standard. You will see the efficiency requirements at all levels are higher for 230v than for 120v. This is not because the EU is more picky than the US, it's because it's possible to build a more efficient power supply when you start with 230v than when you start with 120v. Not all multi voltage power supplies will be more efficient at 230v but most switching power supplies will be, often 2-3% at any load.

It's likely my setup will never pay back the extra cost of the breaker, but I had the 240v UPS so I did it that way. Cost savings are on the order of $5-10 a year on my setup.
